# Can withViewTransitions provide an API for custom animation when jumping to a specific route?

Tags: angular

Can withViewTransitions provide an API for custom animation when jumping to a specific route?

I used RouteReuseStrategy, and then when I right-click the refresh button of the tab, I want to refresh it partially. My plan is to first save the current routing status (path and parameters), then jump from the current route to the "/" route, and then jump back to the current route based on the previously saved status. As a result, the animation of the route jump is visible to the naked eye. The page first returns to the login page, and then returns to the current route. I hope to hide the animation of the route jump at this time.
this is my source code:https://github.com/huajian123/ng-ant-admin
Right-click the refresh button of the tab to see the effect.
The picture below is the key code
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31737260/283996830-f3e3f6b8-395f-4888-a091-f21f4d19250c.png